# How to restrict data by query in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I am new to magento and I am customizing some changes to product, catagory and home pages. I have writen the following Code to show all categories on home page

```
public function getRandomCategory()
{
    $categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $categoryCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');

    return $categoryCollection;
}
```

How would i restrict the data by using a condition in case of * in  ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); statement

Comment: Restrict data... that's not very clear but I will try to cover all cases on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cool thing you can do to debug is to call

```
echo $categoryCollection->getSelect();
```

that will return the exact query that magento is generatingm now the  addAttributeToSelect('*') what it does is to generate the 'Select * From ...' part of the query let's say that you only need to retrieve the category name

In that case you only need to do ->addAttributeToSelect('name') you_ can add multiple  ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute') to retrieve multiple values.

Now if by restrict data you meant to only retrieve the categories WHERE something = tosomething else then you need to use addAttributeToFilter('atttribute', '')value

Check [using_collections_in_magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento) for more information on the

Hope my answer helps